# PHP7 How to create inputs dynamically

Tags: php, php-7

I want to know how I can create my inputs to create an array with the content on that.

When I enter a number with 10 in the numbers input, I wanna to display another input with that counter like.

and before that insert two childs

In the end, i wanna to save that information in a archive.json

```
Number 1
  child 1
  child 2
Number 2
  child 1
  child 2
Number 3
  child 1
  child 2
....
```

> ```
> <form action="beneficiarios.php" method="post">
> <p>Numbers: <input type="text" name="numbers" /></p>
> <p><input type="submit" /></p>
> </form>
> ```

Loading .json
HTML

```
                            <select id="plano">
                                <option>Selecione o seu Plano</option>
                            </select>
```

.JS

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'beneficiarios.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
       $('.plano').val(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       console.log(jqXHR);
       console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
 });
```

.PHP

```
$json_file = file_get_contents("json/planos.json");

$json_str = json_decode($json_file, true);
$itens = $json_str['nome'];

foreach ( $itens as $e ) { 
        echo $e['nome'];
    }
```

I try to loading the information nome on .json in option

Comment: If you want to do this without submitting the form first, it has to be done in JavaScript on the client.

Comment: i aldery do this.

Comment: now i wanna to loading an information from my .json into my combobox, to the user select the information

Comment: Use `json_decode()` to conver the JSON to an array. Then loop over the array creating the `<option>` elements in the `<select>`. There are many tutorials on creating HTML dynamically from arrays, this isn't the place to ask for such basic instruction. Try to implement it first, and if you run into problems post your code.

Comment: I try this, i edit my post.